# Remove all items from a layout

Tags: python, layout, pyqt, pyqt4

I was trying to find something that would take a qt layout and delete everything from it. Just to imagine what the window looks like - I have:

```
QVBoxLayout
     | ------QHboxLayout
                 |---------QWidget
     | ------QHboxLayout
                 |---------QWidget
            .........
```

So I need something that I can call recursively to CLEAR AND DELETE all the stuff from my parent `QVBoxLayout`. I tried things mentioned here ([Clear all widgets in a layout in pyqt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4528347/clear-all-widgets-in-a-layout-in-pyqt)) but none of them work (no correct answer marked anyway). My code looks like this:

```
def clearLayout(self, layout):
    for i in range(layout.count()):
        if (type(layout.itemAt(i)) == QtGui.QHBoxLayout):
            print "layout " + str(layout.itemAt(i))
            self.clearLayout(layout.itemAt(i))
        else:
            print "widget" + str(layout.itemAt(i))
            layout.itemAt(i).widget().close()
```

But it gives an error:

```
               layout.itemAt(i).widget().close()
            AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'close'
```

=>EDIT
This kinda works (but doesn't if there is any other `Layout` than `HBoxLayout`:

```
def clearLayout(self, layout):
    layouts = []
    for i in range(layout.count()):
        if (type(layout.itemAt(i)) == QtGui.QHBoxLayout):
            print "layout " + str(layout.itemAt(i))
            self.clearLayout(layout.itemAt(i))
            layouts.append(layout.itemAt(i))
        else:
            print "widget" + str(layout.itemAt(i))
            if (type(layout.itemAt(i)) == QtGui.QWidgetItem):
                layout.itemAt(i).widget().close()
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The safest way to clear a layout is to extract the items with its [takeAt](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qlayout.html#takeAt) method, and then explicitly delete any widgets with [deleteLater](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qobject.html#deleteLater):

```
def clearLayout(self, layout):
    if layout is not None:
        while layout.count():
            item = layout.takeAt(0)
            widget = item.widget()
            if widget is not None:
                widget.deleteLater()
            else:
                self.clearLayout(item.layout())
```

Comment: This is a more elegant solution. Thank you

Comment: it isn't clear what `self` is in this context

Comment: @pretzlstyle It doesn't really matter what `self` is. The OP's code uses a method of a class, so that's what my answer uses. It could just as easily be function with no `self` at all.

Comment: thanks for the solution, is all I expected to be a built-in method in pyside6

Answer (score 7):

The problem with your code is `QLayout.itemAt()` returns a `QLayoutItem`, `QWidgetItem` or `QSpacerItem` depending on the item at that position. So the condition:

```py
type(layout.itemAt(i)) == QtGui.QHBoxLayout
```

will never be `True` and you will be trying to do `.widget()` for a `QLayoutItem` and that returns `None`. Thus the error you get. Another thing is, you need to loop backwards. Because removing things from the beginning will shift items and change the order of items.

You need to write your function like this:

```py
def clearLayout(self, layout):
    for i in reversed(range(layout.count())):
        item = layout.itemAt(i)

        if isinstance(item, QtGui.QWidgetItem):
            print "widget" + str(item)
            item.widget().close()
            # or
            # item.widget().setParent(None)
        elif isinstance(item, QtGui.QSpacerItem):
            print "spacer " + str(item)
            # no need to do extra stuff
        else:
            print "layout " + str(item)
            self.clearLayout(item.layout())

        # remove the item from layout
        layout.removeItem(item)
```

Comment: almost there but not quite :) Thanks anyway :) When I run the function you supplied all my QHboxLayouts get clasified as spacers. Since this is not true " returns a QLayoutItem, QWidgetItem or QSpacerItem depending on the item at that position." => My itemAt returns QHboxLayout which is not QLayoutItem

Comment: I sorta fixed it like this:                                                                                                       def clearLayout(self, layout):
        for i in range(layout.count()):
            if (type(layout.itemAt(i)) == QtGui.QHBoxLayout):
                print "layout " + str(layout.itemAt(i))
                self.clearLayout(layout.itemAt(i))

            else:
                print "widget" + str(layout.itemAt(i))
                if (type(layout.itemAt(i)) == QtGui.QWidgetItem):
                    layout.itemAt(i).widget().close()

Comment: @user965847: That's weird. I get `QLayoutItem`s for my trials. Anyways, I edited the code. Try this one.