# replacing layout on a QWidget with another layout

Tags: python, layout, qt4, pyqt4

I have a widget which changes when an option is toggled. This invalidates all layouts and widgets. I keep list of all layouts, so I can delete them using something similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9383780/761090):

```
class MyWidget(QFrame):
   # ...
   def reLayout(self):
      def deleteLayoutChilds(l):
         while l.count():
            item=l.takeAt(0)
            widget=item.widget()
            if widget: widget.deleteLater()
            else: deleteLayoutChilds(item.layout())
      for l in self.allLayouts: deleteLayoutChilds(l)

      # now install the new layout
      ##
      ## how to delete the old layout first?
      l=self.layout(); del l # no effect
      #
      layout=QGridLayout(self)
      ## warning: QLayout: Attempting to add QLayout "" to MyWidget "", which already has a layout.
```

How can I get rid of the old layout and set the new one?

---

The documentation is [quite terse](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qwidget.html#setLayout) and apparently not directly applicable to python:

> QWidget.setLayout (self, QLayout)
>
> The QLayout argument has it's ownership transferred to Qt.
>
> Sets the layout manager for this widget to layout.
>
> If there already is a layout manager installed on this widget, QWidget
>   won't let you install another. You must first delete the existing
>   layout manager (returned by layout()) before you can call setLayout()
>   with the new layout.
>
> If layout is the layout manger on a different widget, setLayout() will
>   reparent the layout and make it the layout manager for this widget.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
>  QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout;
>  layout->addWidget(formWidget);
>  setLayout(layout);
> ```
>
> An alternative to calling this function is to pass this widget to the
>   layout's constructor.
>
> The QWidget will take ownership of layout.
>
> See also layout() and Layout Management.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You can simply reparent the layout to a temporary widget:

```
def reLayout(self):
    QWidget().setLayout(self.layout())
    layout = QGridLayout(self)
    ...
```

That will reparent all the child widgets to that temporary object, and that object is deleted immediately along with its new children because we don't keep a reference to it.

But the typical way to have multiple layouts for a single widget and to be able to switch between them is to use a `QStackedWidget` or `QStackedLayout`.

---

And if you still need the answer to that secondary question:

> How to delete the old layout first?

It seems you can't delete directly a `QObject` which has a parent, because the parent is keeping a reference to that object. But you can add the object to a temporary `QObjectCleanupHandler` which, like the above solution, will be deleted with the object(s) it contains immediately:

```
QObjectCleanupHandler().add(self.layout())
```

Comment: +1 for the `QObjectCleanupHandler()` solution to delete the layout.

Comment: The temporary QWidget solution is as smart as the idiom of C++ assignment operator.  So you do not need worry about destuction of children of the old layout.

Comment: I think `QStackedWidget` and `QStackedLayout` are for displaying multiple widgets, not multiple layouts for a single widget. Nonetheless, the reparenting solution is very handy!