# Using an instance of one class in another

Tags: python, class

It is a simple stack display program with a GUI using PyQt5 and Python3.3.
Gui Program error areas highlighted in between `###Error####`

```
#Modules
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtCore, QtWidgets
import stacks_queues

#Classes
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    '''Main Window'''

    #Constructor
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow,self).__init__()
        self.createUI()   

    #Methods

###Error###
    def createUI(self):
        self.stack = stacks_queues.Stack()
        #Title
        self.setWindowTitle('Section 2.4: Stacks and queues')
        #Window Components
        self.mainViewWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        #Layouts
        self.mainViewWidget.setLayout(self.mainGrid(self.stack))
        self.setCentralWidget(self.mainViewWidget)
###Error###

    def mainGrid(self,stack):
        #Layout components
        self.mainLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.addRemoveLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.pushButtonLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        #Create components
        #Labels
        self.titleLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel('Implementation of a Stack', self)
        self.counterLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel('Number of items in stack: 0', self)
        self.contentsLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel('Contents of stack', self)
        self.addWordLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel('Word to add:', self)
        self.removeWordLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel('Word being removed', self)
        #Buttons
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Push', self)
        self.popButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Pop', self)
        #Line Edit
        self.addWordLineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit('', self)
        self.removeWordLineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit('Test', self)
        self.removeWordLineEdit.isReadOnly()
        #Text Edit
        self.stackTextEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit('', self)
        self.stackTextEdit.isReadOnly()
        #Add Widgets
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.titleLabel)
        self.addRemoveLayout.addWidget(self.addWordLabel, 0,0)
        self.addRemoveLayout.addWidget(self.removeWordLabel, 1,0)
        self.addRemoveLayout.addWidget(self.addWordLineEdit, 0,1)
        self.addRemoveLayout.addWidget(self.removeWordLineEdit, 1,1)
        self.mainLayout.addLayout(self.addRemoveLayout)
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.contentsLabel)
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.stackTextEdit)
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.counterLabel)
        self.pushButtonLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        self.pushButtonLayout.addWidget(self.popButton)
        self.mainLayout.addLayout(self.pushButtonLayout)
        #Connections
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.pushStack(self.stack))
        self.popButton.clicked.connect(self.popStack)
        return self.mainLayout

###Error###
    def pushStack(self,stack):
        item = self.addWordLineEdit.text()
        self.stack.push(item)
        #Re-draw Window
        self.mainViewWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.mainViewWidget.setLayout(self.mainGrid(self.stack))
        self.setCentralWidget(self.mainViewWidget)
###Error###

    def popStack(self):
        #Not finished yet
        pass


#Functions
def Main():
    '''Main Program'''
    #Creates new application
    application = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    #Creates new instance of MainWindow
    mainWindow = MainWindow()
    #Display MainWindow
    mainWindow.show()
    #Keep MainWindow on top
    mainWindow.raise_()
    #Monitor for events
    application.exec_()
#Run Main
Main()
```

Imported program

```
class Stack():
    '''Stack data'''
    #Attributes
    items = []
    maxsize = 0

    #Methods
    def push(self,item):
        self.items.append(item)

    def pop(self,item):
        self.items.pop()

    def isEmpty(self):
        if self.items:
            return False
        else:
            return True

    def size(self):
        self.maxsize = len(self.items)
```

The error is  1993 lines long so I will only show the main errors that keep repeating.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Luke\Documents\A-Level-Work\A2\Computing\COMP 3\stack_queues_gui.py", line 92, in <module>
    Main()
  File "C:\Users\Luke\Documents\A-Level-Work\A2\Computing\COMP 3\stack_queues_gui.py",     line 84, in Main
    mainWindow = MainWindow()
  File "C:\Users\Luke\Documents\A-Level-Work\A2\Computing\COMP 3\stack_queues_gui.py",     line 13, in __init__
    self.createUI()
  File "C:\Users\Luke\Documents\A-Level-Work\A2\Computing\COMP 3\stack_queues_gui.py", line 23, in createUI
    self.mainViewWidget.setLayout(self.mainGrid(self.stack))
  File "C:\Users\Luke\Documents\A-Level-Work\A2\Computing\COMP 3\stack_queues_gui.py",     line 62, in mainGrid
    self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.pushStack(self.stack))
  File "C:\Users\Luke\Documents\A-Level-Work\A2\Computing\COMP 3\stack_queues_gui.py",         line 71, in pushStack
```

The error keeps repeating with lines 62 and 71 only until python exceeds its maximum recursion depth.

The massive error only occurred once I had added `pushStack` so I have no idea how to fix this as I only have A2-level python knowledge. The program was fine with `Stack` being called into `MainWindow` and being used in `mainGrid`.

Comment: You mean you have an `InfiniteRecursion` exception here? You cut off the actual exception message.

Comment: I'm curious. What do you mean by `A2-level python knowledge`?

Comment: A2-level python knowledge means that all my coding knowledge comes from an A-level syllabus which is a qualification in sixth form in England. So i'm crap basically.

Comment: Ah, I see. I wouldn't call you crap. You at least have a grasp of the language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You created an infinite recursion:

```
 def mainGrid(self,stack):
     # ...
    self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.pushStack(self.stack))
```

calls

```
def pushStack(self,stack):
    # ...
    self.mainViewWidget.setLayout(self.mainGrid(self.stack))
```

See the `self.mainGrid()` there? But `self.mainGrid()` calls `self.pushStack()`, and nowhere in your code do you break out of that loop.

You need to remove one or the other call here, or determine what the recursive call is supposed to achieve and create conditions where one of the two methods does *not* call the other.

Most likely you don't have to recreate the `self.mainViewWidget` from scratch each time you push something on the stack. Also, if you meant `self.pushStack` to be called when the `pushButton` is *clicked* (and not when you connect up the action to the button), you need to *not* call it directly:

```
self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.pushStack)
```

Note that now the `self.pushStack` *method* is connected, not the return value.

There is *no reason* to pass `self.stack` to `self.pushStack()` here; that method can access `self.stack` without the `stack` argument too

```
def pushStack(self):
    # ...
    self.stack.push(item)
```

Comment: Thanks that had been driving me mad for ages! The reason it re-makes the screen is that when the program is finished it will update the text edit box to show all the data in the stack. Unless you meant that there is a way to refresh it with new data, which would make things a lot easier but i don't know how.

Comment: I am not too familiar with Qt, to be honest. Does [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10416582/replacing-layout-on-a-qwidget-with-another-layout) help?

Comment: That is more to do with changing the layout than refreshing it with new data.