# QT - QPixmap not rescaling with current parent size

Tags: qt, python-3.x, pyqt, qt5, pyqt5

I'm trying to build a `topBar` to put in other widgets `layout` but I don't know why the **`QPixmap is not rescaling as we change the application window size**. Here's the code:

*`QPixmap` is within `QLabel` within a `QHBoxLayout` of a `QWidget` that is the `centralWidget` of a `QMainWindow`*

**QT 5.8 - Python 3.6**

I've updated this code and deleted the previous version on March 24, 2017.

**0 - Dependencies**

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
import sys
```

**1 - Main Window**

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        print("I've been in main window")
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle("I'm here, the main window")
```

**2 - Top Bar**

```
class topBar(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        print("I've been in topBar")
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setObjectName("topBar")
        self.setStyleSheet("""
        QWidget {background-color: pink;}
        QLabel {background-color: green; }""")

    def resizeEvent(self,event):
        resizeHandler(self,event) # You'll see this little dude right next
```

**3 - The `resizeEvent` Handler, that's were I believe the *issue* is**

```
def resizeHandler(self,event):
    print(" I've been in resizeHandler")
    if self.objectName() == "topBar":
        print("I've been resizing the topBar")
        logo = QPixmap('some_Image')
        # Debug
        # You'll be able to see that it does re-scale, but it's not updating the Pixmap.
        logo.scaled(event.size(),Qt.KeepAspectRatio).save("pixmap.png")
        # ...
        logoContainer = QLabel()
        logoContainer.setPixmap(logo.scaled(event.size(),Qt.KeepAspectRatio,Qt.FastTransformation))  
        logoContainer.setMaximumSize(logo.width(),logo.height())

        containerLayout = QHBoxLayout()
        containerLayout.addWidget(logoContainer,0)

        container = QWidget()
        container.setLayout(containerLayout)

        # Layout
        layout = QHBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(container,0)

        self.setLayout(layout)

        main.setCentralWidget(self)
```

**4 - Testing**

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("I've been in __main__")
    app = 0
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.aboutToQuit.connect(app.deleteLater)
    app.setWindowIcon(QIcon('someIcon'))

    main = MainWindow() 
    main.layout().setSizeConstraint(QLayout.SetNoConstraint)

    bar = topBar()
    main.setCentralWidget(bar)
    main.show()
    app.exec_()
```

If it's possible I'd also like to limit `topBar` it`self` to not exceed 20% of the current screen size vertically (`setMaximumHeight`? But based on what?) but I'm not sure how.

Thanks!

Comment: What makes you think `container` isn't scaling?  Change `self.setStyleSheet("""` to `container.setStyleSheet("""` and you'll see `container` scaling until it reaches the maximum size that you've set.  Is the real problem not that `logo` isn't scaling?

Comment: For a moment I thought container was not being resized as the current screen shrinks or expands. I've been trying many approaches for the past 3 days on this very simple problem but I was unable to solve it. Latest approach I removed `setScaledContents(True)` and tried re-defining the `resizeEvent` to update the pixmap to `pixmap.scaled(main.width(),main.height(),Qt.KeepAspectRatio)` but that didn't work either =/. (*main being `QMainWindow` and `topBar` being the `CentralWidget`*)

Comment: @G.M. I've updated the question and the code, it seems like the real problem is that `QPixmap` is not updating its size.

Answer (score 0):

To get a widget to fill out the container, you would want to set the vertical and horizontal size policy to either minimum, expanding, minimum expanding, or ignored. http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsizepolicy.html#Policy-enum

As far as the second question, it's not a built-in feature of Qt widgets. You might get better luck with QML or Web Engine. You could create a sub-class of QWidget that uses setGeometry() and some window calculation to constrain its size.

Comment: Tried both `[*].setSizePolicy([policy1],[policy2])` with policy being a pair of `QSizePolicy.MinimumExpanding`and `QSizePolicy.Expanding` but it's still not rescaling. I don't know if the `QLabel` is not rescaling or if it is the `container` `QWidget`. Thanks for your repply!

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking at the wrong thing here when trying to diagnose the problem.

Your last comment states...

> the real problem is that QPixmap is not updating its size

That's because the `QLabel` that's displaying it isn't being resized.  Going back to your original code I think all you need to do is insert a layout between `container` and the `QLabel` `logo`...

```
class topBar(QWidget):
def __init__(self,parent):
    super().__init__()

    container = QWidget()
    container.setMaximumSize(587,208)
    container.setMinimumSize(0,0)

    ## Logo
    logo = QLabel(container)
    #logo = QLabel(container_layout)
    logo.setPixmap(QPixmap('.some_image_in_the_current_working_dir.png'))
    logo.setScaledContents(1)

    # G.M.
    container_layout = QHBoxLayout(container)
    container_layout.addWidget(logo)

    # Layout
    ## to center content horizontally in wrapper w/o preventing rescale
    layout = QHBoxLayout(self)
    layout.addWidget(container)

    self.setStyleSheet("""
    QWidget {background-color: red;}
    QLabel {background-color: green; Qt::KeepAspectRatio;}""")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = 0
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.aboutToQuit.connect(app.deleteLater)
    test = topBar(None)
    test.show()
    app.exec_()
```

(Look for the G.M. comment)

The code above simply creates a layout `container_layout` for `container` and makes `logo` a child of it.  That appears to solve the problem I *think* you're describing.

Comment: I've managed to achieve the same output of your code before, but it's still not keeping the aspect ratio, I guess `Qt::KeepAspectRatio` on the `StyleSheet` isn't helping with that.

Comment: As for the *new* code, I've tried `logoContainer.setStyleSheet(".Qlabel {background-color: purple;}")` on it and I've seen that the `QLabel` is resizing, `QPixmap` still not.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of debugging and reading here and there I came up with the following solution (using `numpy` to help with the rescaling):

```
def resizeHandler(self,event):
    if self.objectName() == "topBar":
        # Wiping the old layout
        temp = QWidget()
        temp.setLayout(self.layout())

        # Pixmap
        logoPixmap = QPixmap('./img/exampleImage.png')

        # Label
        logoLabel = QLabel()
        logoLabel.setPixmap(logoPixmap)
        logoLabel.setScaledContents(True)

        ## Label Container Layout
        containerLayout = QHBoxLayout()
        containerLayout.addWidget(logoLabel,0)

        # Label Container
        logoContainer = QWidget()
        logoContainer.setLayout(containerLayout)

        # Finding the width and height of the scaled box
        # Image unit vectors
        imageSize = np.array((logoPixmap.width(),logoPixmap.height()))
        screenSize = np.array((event.size().width(),event.size().height()))

        # Proportion of each dimension in relation to the smallest side
        # Note that one will always be the unit vector and the other greater than a unit
        screenUVec = screenSize / screenSize.min()
        imageUVec = imageSize / imageSize.min()


        # minBorder 11 is the distance between the Application vertical border and the central widget
        # 22 is the minimum height where the CentralWidget begins to appear 
        # Which should vary according to the height of menubar and statsbar of the QMainWindow
        minBorder = np.array([11,22]) *2
        screenSize -= minBorder
        for axis,size in enumerate(screenSize):
            if size < 0:
                screenSize[axis] = 0
        maxSize = np.zeros(2)

        # Ideal ratio based on the maxSide
        ratio =  int(round(screenSize[imageUVec.argmax()] / imageUVec.max() - 0.49999999))

        if ratio >=1 and 0 not in screenSize: # Image is scalable on the current screen
            maxSize[imageUVec.argmin()] = min(screenSize[imageUVec.argmin()],ratio) # We should add imageSize[imageUVec.argmin()] if we want to limit the maxSize to the maximum size of the image
            maxSize[imageUVec.argmax()] = maxSize[imageUVec.argmin()] * imageUVec.max()
            sizeUVec = maxSize / maxSize.min()


        # Layout
        layout = QHBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(logoContainer,0)
        logoLabel.setMaximumSize(QSize(maxSize[0],maxSize[1]))
        self.setLayout(layout)
```

A special thanks to [@alexisdm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/894321/alexisdm), he showed me [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10416582/replacing-layout-on-a-qwidget-with-another-layout) that we should first **wipe the old layout**. When I started watching the `globals` I saw that several layouts were stacked.

As for the rescaling part, I still went through an unconventional path, but it's behaving the way I want.