# How to delete layout in Pyqt

Tags: python, qt

My Code:

```
Ui_startscreen.setupUi(self,self.areaplace)
self.FRAME_BUTTON.mousePressEvent = self.open_sec_view;
def open_sec_view(self,e):
     Ui_sec.setupUi(self,self.areaplace);
```

Okey and now I have three python files, first -> start-program.py, second -> main.py, third -> secview.py

start-program.py is base QT GUI file with blank frame -> self.areaplace
when program start self.areaplace include Ui_startscreen(main.py).
During the click Ui_startscreen -> self.FRAME_BUTTON I need remove self.areaplace layout and clear view but when I'm using:

```
self.horizontalLayout.deleteLater()
self.areaplace.findChild(QtGui.QWidget).deleteLater()
```

console return me this error:

```
QLayout: Attempting to add QLayout "" to QWidget "secview", which already has a layout
```

I know I must to delete/remove layout but I don't know how :/
When I  comment horizontalLayout every works fine but I have a lot of files and I need to use function to delete layout
Can you help me ? :)

Answer (score 1):

The best decision that I found on this problem is to have the one Layout e.g. `mainlayout = QHBoxLayout()`. As kind of Layout-conteiner. Then you `self.setLayout(mainlayout)`. Then you can do things like `self.layout().addLayout(whateverlayoutyouwantedtoseehere)` and when you need to change just do
`self.layout().takeAt(0)` and `self.layout().addLayout(anotherlayoutyouwantedamomentlater)`. There may occure necessity in recursive destroying your previous layout, it can be done [like that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9383780/3856692)