# What is the best way of deleting a qpushbutton

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt4, qtgui

Hello I need to know a way of deleting a QPushButton from my interface, i have not found a way that i
s usefull for my program.

for example:

```
class Button(QtGui.QPushButton):

    def __init__(self, title, parent):
        super(Button, self).__init__(title, parent)

        self.setAcceptDrops(True)

    def dragEnterEvent(self, e):

        if e.mimeData().hasFormat('text/plain'):
            e.accept()
        else:
            e.ignore() 

    def dropEvent(self, e):
        self.setText(e.mimeData().text()) 


class Example(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        edit = QtGui.QLineEdit('', self)
        edit.setDragEnabled(True)
        edit.move(30, 65)

        button = Button("Button", self)
        button.move(190, 65)

        self.setWindowTitle('Simple drag & drop')
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 150)


def main():

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    ex.show()
    app.exec_()  



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

there i created a button that can be dragged and dropped in my main window
now i want a way to delete this button from the mainwindow while im in the program.

thanks

Comment: It's not clear what do you want.

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4528347/clear-all-widgets-in-a-layout-in-pyqt