# Replacing pyqt5 widgets issue

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5, qtwidgets

I have widget with some labels placed grid-like.
Code:

```
    def init_drawers(self):
        self.drawers_widget = QWidget(self)

        width, height = self.get_drawers_size() # ex.: 12, 8
        self.drawers_widget.setGeometry(100, 0, width * 32, height * 32)

        for h in range(height):
            for w in range(width):
                drawer_uid = f"{h}_{w}"

                label = QLabel(self.drawers_widget)
                label.setGeometry(w * 32, h * 32, 32, 32)
                label.mousePressEvent = self.get_generic_clicker(drawer_uid)
                self.bindings[drawer_uid] = (h, w) # {}

                self.drawers[drawer_uid] = label # {}

        self.render_all()
```

`render_all` just iterates over `self.drawers` and sets 32x32 pixmaps for them, so in result I get big image with clickable fields that change their pixmap on click.

At first everything works fine, but then I need to change layout to, for example, 9*9.
I tried to delete labels:

```
if self.drawers:
    for k in self.drawers:
         self.drawers[k].close() # or .deleteLater()
    self.drawers.clear()
    self.bindings.clear()
```

And call `init_drawers` again (`drawers_widget` init was out of that function). Main widget resized, but no labels seen - and also they're not responding to clicks.
While using `.destroy()` instead - click events print new ids, but pixmaps do not update. Also tried to delete `drawers_widget` too and create it again - same result.

UPD: I get no errors in console.

Comment: do you get error when you run it in console? always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: @furas no, console is clean. Added this note to question.

Comment: Widgets must be explicitly shown if created as children *after* the parent has been already shown. Obviously, if you properly use [layout managers](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html), that is implicit.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I still don't get why newly created labels with QWidget parent are not displayed, but for my case I've made workaround using @musicamante [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73925384/replacing-pyqt5-widgets-issue#comment130530597_73925384)

```
    def init_drawers(self):
        self.draw_widget = QWidget(self)
        self.draw_grid = QGridLayout(self.draw_widget)
        self.draw_grid.setSpacing(0)
        self.draw_grid.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)

        self.setup_drawers()

    def setup_drawers(self):
        # cleanup
        if self.draw_grid.count():
            for i in reversed(range(self.draw_grid.count())):
                self.draw_grid.itemAt(i).widget().setParent(None)

        width, height = self.get_drawers_size()
        self.draw_widget.setGeometry(100, 0, width * 32, height * 32)

        for h in range(height):
            for w in range(width):

                label = QLabel()
                label.setFixedSize(32, 32)
                self.draw_grid.addWidget(label, h, w)

        self.render_all()
```

Calling `setup_drawers` later does just what I need.
Cleanup method is from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13103617/17427984) and I'm not sure that this is safe, but if I change it to `.deleteLater()` then after second reload app crashes with
`Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)`
(no traceback or something)